# Cannot set Graph Editor Evaluation Time keyframe handle type to Free

Tags: keyframes, graph-editor

I'm animating the *Evaluation Time* corresponding to an object constrained-animated on the curve. But I can't find a way to smooth out this keyframe. I tried setting *Handle Type* to *Free* or *Aligned* but nothing happens. I noticed that when I animate another object, you can see a handle type.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you set interpolation to bezier...this happens: (i hope this is what you wanna have?)

[image]

Comment: oh ok. i was using interpolation sinusoidal and then wondering why i couldnt use bezier handles XD. so i guess i can use bezier interpolation and then adjust the handles to have the same sinusoidal shape. thank you!

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: but i wonder why can't it automatically add the bezier handles if i set the interpolation to sinusoidal?

Comment: it could, i am sure - ask the developers ;)

Comment: Question is, can you describe sinusoidal interpolation as a Bezier? I know you can't describe a circle as a Bezier perfectly... Attempt one by scaling to 0 one of the handles: https://i.imgur.com/tRsSYzw.png Attempt 2, by eyeballing arbitrary handle positions, but I don't know what's the logic: https://i.imgur.com/EaEJKFN.png

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady that's interesting. thank you for sharing! i always thought circles can be described perfectly with Bezier. apparently not xd but i guess rough estimations for any interpolation described as bezier will suffice for any animation.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie One more thing, since recently you can use ghost curves for easier manual workflow: https://i.imgur.com/U9osA9X.gif In the past I would take a screenshot, open in a new webbrowser window, use Autohotkey to set the window to be semitransparent and clickthrough and position it on the old spot xD Much easier now.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady wow that was some hardcore tedious work haha but now awesome! very useful thank you for sharing!